# Checking if a column exists in a sheet and if exists copies data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the vba code to check if a column exists in a particular sheet, and if it exists paste the column contents to another sheet, if it doesn't exist print 0 in another sheet

Comment: What have you already tried?  You need to show what efforts you have made to solve the problem, and why it's not working - have a read of [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

I searched and found this link https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html

You can refer to a member of the collection, for example, a single Worksheet object, in three ways.

> 1. Using the worksheet name.
>
> Worksheets("Sales").Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

---

> 2. Using the index number (1 is the first worksheet starting from the left).
>
> Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

---

> 3. Using the CodeName.
>
> Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

For counting empty columns I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta

> Example to check if column D is empty
>
> IIf(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("D")) = 0

---

> To copy data I found
>   https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/

Try something and then update your question if you have doubts.